# Using control defined in XAML in another thread

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am playng around with the library found [here](http://microsoftdwayneneed.codeplex.com/), which is to help render the UI on multiple threads.  The sample works fine and does what it's supposed to but I wanted to modify it a little.

In the sample, the visual element that is to be rendered on a separate thread is defined/created in the code behind.  Here is some of the sample code:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="VisualTargetDemo.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Microsoft.DwayneNeed.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.DwayneNeed"
    Title="VisualTargetDemo"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
    Loaded="OnLoaded"
    >
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <local:VisualWrapper Grid.Column="0" Width="200" Height="100" x:Name="Player1"/>
    <local:VisualWrapper Grid.Column="1" Width="200" Height="100" x:Name="Player2"/>
    <local:VisualWrapper Grid.Column="2" Width="200" Height="100" x:Name="Player3"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.DwayneNeed.Controls;
using Microsoft.DwayneNeed.Threading;

namespace VisualTargetDemo
{
    public partial class Window1 : System.Windows.Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Player1.Child = CreateMediaElementOnWorkerThread();
            Player2.Child = CreateMediaElementOnWorkerThread();
            Player3.Child = CreateMediaElementOnWorkerThread();
        }

        private HostVisual CreateMediaElementOnWorkerThread()
        {
            // Create the HostVisual that will "contain" the VisualTarget
            // on the worker thread.
            HostVisual hostVisual = new HostVisual();

            // Spin up a worker thread, and pass it the HostVisual that it
            // should be part of.
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(MediaWorkerThread));
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Start(hostVisual);

            // Wait for the worker thread to spin up and create the VisualTarget.
            s_event.WaitOne();

            return hostVisual;
        }

        private FrameworkElement CreateMediaElement()
        {
            // Create a MediaElement, and give it some video content.
            MediaElement mediaElement = new MediaElement();
            mediaElement.BeginInit();
            mediaElement.Source = new Uri("http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/C/4/2C433161-F56C-4BAB-BBC5-B8C6F240AFCC/SL_0410_448x256_300kb_2passCBR.wmv?amp;clcid=0x409");
            mediaElement.Width = 200;
            mediaElement.Height = 100;
            mediaElement.EndInit();

            return mediaElement;
        }

        private void MediaWorkerThread(object arg)
        {
            // Create the VisualTargetPresentationSource and then signal the
            // calling thread, so that it can continue without waiting for us.
            HostVisual hostVisual = (HostVisual)arg;
            VisualTargetPresentationSource visualTargetPS = new VisualTargetPresentationSource(hostVisual);
            s_event.Set();

            // Create a MediaElement and use it as the root visual for the
            // VisualTarget.
            visualTargetPS.RootVisual = CreateMediaElement();

            // Run a dispatcher for this worker thread.  This is the central
            // processing loop for WPF.
            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
        }

        private static AutoResetEvent s_event = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    }
}
```

So OnLoaded creates and sets the Child property of the VisualWrapper.  What I would like to do is allow the user to define which control to assign to Child directly in the XAML, something like:

```
<local:VisualWrapper Grid.Column="0" Width="200" Height="100" x:Name="Player1"/>               
  <local:VisualWrapper.ChildSource>
    <Button>TEST</Button>
  </local:VisualWrapper.ChildSource>
</View:VisualWrapper>
```

The plan was to add a ChildSource DependencyProperty to the VisualWrapper class and whenever that property changes, recreate it's Child content.  The problem is that when I try to access the ChildSource control from within the VisualWrapper:

```
public FrameworkElement ChildSource
{
    get { return (FrameworkElement)this.GetValue(ChildSourceProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(ChildSourceProperty, value); }
}
```

I get an error: "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.".  I can't get it to work and am wondering if it's even possible.

I tried using the Dispatcher in the getter:

```
public FrameworkElement ChildSource
{
    get { return (FrameworkElement)Dispatcher.Invoke((Delegate)GetValue(ChildSourceProperty)); }
    set { this.SetValue(ChildSourceProperty, value); }
}
```

But that didn't work.  My feeling is that some Disaptcher.Invoke would be required but I am not sure where.

Can what I am trying to do be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

WPF creates objects with thread affinity, and those objects can only then be used from the thread which created them. This means if you want to split your UI between threads each control must be created on the thread that is going to use it.